# Remove Duplicates and take maximum values for other records while merging two files in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files a.txt and b.txt with 6 columns each. I want to merge both files and remove exact duplicates based on all 6 columns while for other cases I would like to have maximum of column 3,4,5,6 based on grouping of column 1 and 2. I would like to explain this by an example below

File a.txt

Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5      Col6

A1        B1         1         1          1        1

A2        B2         1         0          0        1

File b.txt

Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5      Col6

A1        B1         1         1          1        1

A2        B2         0         1          0        1

Result should be :

Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5      Col6

A1        B1         1         1          1        1

A2        B2         1         1          0        1

So grouping is on Col1 and Col2 and if other 4 columns have same value in both files they are exact duplicates and duplicate should be removed but if they have different values in both the files then max value or 1 should be selected

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts in their question so kindly do edit your question with your efforts(there is nothing right or wrong here as we all are here for learning) and let us know then.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with _then max value or 1 should be selected_. So If I have `A A 0 0 1 2` and `A A 0 0 9 3` the result should be `A A 0 0 1 3`?

Comment: Hi, actually the values are either 1 or 0 , so if any one file has value as 1, 1 should be selected and if both have 0 then 0 should be selcted

Answer (score 1):

Using a mix of `sort -u` to get rid of the duplicates and [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to find the max values of each group's columns makes it trivial:

```sh
$ sort -u a.txt b.txt | datamash -W -g1,2 max 3-6
A1  B1  1   1   1   1
A2  B2  1   1   0   1
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the reply, but the issue is that datamash can not be provided on our server.

Answer (score 0):

a two step approach will be easier.

First define a function to create key for join

```
$ f() { awk '{print $1"_"$2 "\t" $0}' "$1" | sort; }
```

join the files with the key, and let awk pick the max of each field

```
$ join <(f file1) <(f file2) | 
  awk 'function max(x,y) {return x>y?x:y}
      {n=(NF+1)/2; 
       printf "%s %s",$2,$3; 
       for(i=4;i<=n;i++) printf " %s",max($i,$(i+n-1)); 
       print ""}'

A1 B1 1 1 1 1
A2 B2 1 1 0 1
```